# present a static page url as different url which is SEO friendly

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, friendly-url

I have developed a site, which has some static pages. Like explore, home, feedback.

The link for these goes as follows
website.com/views/explore.php
website.com/index.php
website.com/views/feedback.php

I want to write a different SEO URL for each of the URL mentioned above.
Is it possible ?
i.e. for example
**website.com/views/explore.php should be convereted/visible as website.com/explore**
**website.com/views/feedback.php should be convereted/visible as website.com/give/feedback**

and so on

Comment: website.com/explore definitely is easier on the eyes than website.com/views/explore.php but is it really more likely to be picked up by a search engine? I'm skeptical.

Comment: what's strengthening your doubt on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules to rewrite requests to `/explore` and `/give/feedback` internally to `/views/explore.php` and `/views/feedback.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^explore$ views/explore.php [L]
RewriteRule ^give/feedback$ views/feedback.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gumbo, will these rules work on localhost also ? Or shall I test it after editing and then uploading the file on server ?

Comment: Thanks again for your timely help. :) working flawlessly on localhost too.

Answer (score 0):

with .htaccess file you can change any url on your site. i love this file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are hosting website in ISS the you can try IIS SEO toolkit. & set dynamic URL itself in IIS
see the indepth explaination by [Scott about Imporve SEO by SEO Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx)